# Having problems binding ObservableDictionary in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I copied this ObservableDictionary implementation from a VS2013 generated project.  It is a strongly typed implementation (Key is string and Value is object). However, I must be getting the bindings wrong because I don't see any data, I get a BindingExpression path error.
One thing I note is that the MapChangedEventHandler is always null, meaning that nobody every registered for the event!
1. Who or what registers for the MapChangedEventHandler?
2. What should my bindings be?  I've tried several VARIOUS permutations of bindings.  All to no avail, but here's the latest permutation of the code:

```
    public class ObservableDictionary : IObservableMap<string, object>
{
    private class ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs : IMapChangedEventArgs<string>
    {
        public ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs(CollectionChange change, string key)
        {
            this.CollectionChange = change;
            this.Key = key;
        }

        public CollectionChange CollectionChange { get; private set; }
        public string Key { get; private set; }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public event MapChangedEventHandler<string, object> MapChanged;

    private void InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange change, string key)
    {
        var eventHandler = MapChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs(change, key));
        }
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        this._dictionary.Add(key, value);
        this.InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange.ItemInserted, key);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        if (this._dictionary.Remove(key))
        {
            this.InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange.ItemRemoved, key);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        object currentValue;
        if (this._dictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out currentValue) &&
            Object.Equals(item.Value, currentValue) && this._dictionary.Remove(item.Key))
        {
            this.InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange.ItemRemoved, item.Key);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dictionary[key];
        }
        set
        {
            this._dictionary[key] = value;
            this.InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange.ItemChanged, key);
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        var priorKeys = this._dictionary.Keys.ToArray();
        this._dictionary.Clear();
        foreach (var key in priorKeys)
        {
            this.InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange.ItemRemoved, key);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get { return this._dictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return this._dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        return this._dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<object> Values
    {
        get { return this._dictionary.Values; }
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return this._dictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this._dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        int arraySize = array.Length;
        foreach (var pair in this._dictionary)
        {
            if (arrayIndex >= arraySize) break;
            array[arrayIndex++] = pair;
        }
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<custom:RESTAPHandler
x:Class="K1MobilePhone.Views.HomePageAdmin"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:K1MobilePhone.Utilities"
xmlns:cells="clr-namespace:K1MobilePhone.Common"
xmlns:wptoolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="phoneApplicationPage_Loaded" Margin="0,6,0,-6">
<custom:RESTAPHandler.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="sd_source" Source="{Binding Path=SDSummaries, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="ticketsViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Tickets, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</custom:RESTAPHandler.Resources>
```

And now the xaml.cs:

```
   public sealed partial class HomePageAdmin : RESTAPHandler
{
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel { get { return this.defaultViewModel; } }

    public HomePageAdmin() : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this.DefaultViewModel;
        this.DefaultViewModel["SDSummaries"] = new SDSummaries();
        this.DefaultViewModel["Tickets"] = new RecentlyViewedTickets();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I wasn't able to ever figure out why I couldn't access string-based keys in my xaml code.  The default Windows store app works great.  What I wound up doing is this:

Page.xaml:

```
   <custom:RESTAPHandler.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="sd_source"/>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="ticketsViewSource"/>
</custom:RESTAPHandler.Resources>
```

I built everything up in the code-behind:

```
    public sealed partial class HomePageAdmin : RESTAPHandler
{
    private Grid visibleGrid;
    private SDSummaries _sdSummaries = new SDSummaries();
    public SDSummaries SDSummaries { get { return this._sdSummaries; } }

    public HomePageAdmin() : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.sd_source.Source = this.SDSummaries;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }


    private void phoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Address = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["URL"];
    }

    private void TicketsStatsResponse (TicketsStatsResponse response)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            PlainTitleDisclosureCellItem cell = (PlainTitleDisclosureCellItem)this.SDSummaries[1];
            cell.Label = response.NewTicketCount.ToString();
            cell = (PlainTitleDisclosureCellItem)this.SDSummaries[2];
            cell.Label = response.UnassignedTicketCount.ToString();
        });
    }
```

Seems a bit of a hack, but I'm not sure.